Mobile.BuildTools for MAUI
I am trying to setup Mobile.BuildTools for MAUI. Currently I am using Xamarin Forms, Mobile.BuildTools V1.4(Secrets.json) with Microsoft App center deployment. which is working fine.
I am migrating my mobile app to MAUI now and trying to setup the Mobile.BuildTools V2(appsettings.json). but it is not generating the static file as expected. I will be setting up Azure devops pipline for deployments.
I followed these steps:
1. Installed Mobile.BuildTools Nuget
2. created buildtools.json file in the solution directory.
3. created appsettings.json in the MAUI project.

I am not sure what's missing here, is there any additional setup needed in the .csproj file or buildtools.json file?

I am assuming you have been through the documentation?

yes @FreakyAli tried lot of variations. right now i am willing to consider other ways of managing the app settings by environment using Azure devops pipelines. if there is another way please do suggest.
